# Prove by induction that $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} (2i + 1)^2 = \frac{(n + 1)(2n + 1)(2n + 3)}{3} (\forall n \geq 0)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} (2i + 1)^2 = \frac{(n + 1)(2n + 1)(2n + 3)}{3} (\forall n \geq 0)$$

I got the idea of proof by induction. First, basis step: $P(1)$ and $10 = 10$. 
Second, inductive step: we put $P(n+1)$ and assume its true, but what we do after that?

Comment: Your basis step should be showing that $P(0)$ is true.

Comment: You don't put p(n+1) and assume it is true.  You assume it is true for some $n = k$ (which it is; it is true for $n = k = 1$) and then prove that *that* would imply it is true for $n = k+ 1$.  So $P(k+ 1) = P(k) + (2k + 1)^2 = (k+1)(2k+1)(2k + 3)/3+ (2k + 1)^2 $.  Does that equal $$P(k+ 1) = P(k) + (2k + 1)^2 = (k+1)(2k+1)(2k + 3)/3+ (2k + 1)^2  ?=?  (k + 2)(2(k+1) + 1)(2(k+1) + 3) /3$$???  If so you are done.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do NOT "put p(n+1) and assume its true".  You assume p(n) is true for some k, then use that to **prove** p(n+1).

Problems like this with "sums to n" are especially well suited to "proof by induction" since p(n+1) is p(n) plus a new term.  Here, $p(n+1)= p(n)+ (2(n+1)+1)^2= p(n)+ (4n+ 3)^2= p(n)+ 16n^2+ 24n+ 9$.  Since $p(n)= (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)/3$, we want to prove that $(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)/3+ 16n^2+ 24n+ 9= (n+1+1)(2(n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+3)/3.

Answer (score 1):

Put
$$P (n)=\sum_0^n (2i+1)^2$$
and
$$Q(n)=(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)/3$$

$P (\color {red}{0 })=Q (\color {red} {0}). $

LET $n\geq \color {red} 0\;\;:$

$$P (n)=Q (n) $$
we must prove that
$$P (n+1)=Q (n+1). $$

$$P(n+1)=P (n)+(2 (n+1)+1)^2$$
$$=Q(n)+(2n+3)^2$$
$$=(2n+3)\left ((n+1)(2n+1)/3+(2n+3)\right) $$
$$=\frac 13 (2n+3)(2n^2+3n+1+6n+9) $$

$$\frac 13(2n+3)(2n^2+9n+10) $$
$$=\frac 13 (2n+3)(2n+5)(n+2) $$

$$=Q (n+1) $$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what the next step is, then you didn't get the idea of the proof by induction.
After the first step, you consider $P(n)$ as true and conclude $P(n+1)$ to be true.
Which means, that you proof $P(n+1)$ using $P(n)$ as a fact. In the case of such an equation, you start with the leftandside of $P(n+1)$ and try to envolve it such that you get the lefthandside of $P(n)$. Here: $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}(2i+1)^2=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n(2i+1)\right)+(2(n+1)+1)$. Then you use P(n) to get the righthandside of $P(n+1)$.